# 'MissingPluginException' is not a subtype of type 'String' error in flutter local notification

Tags: flutter, localnotification

I tried the following code. It's giving 'MissingPluginException' is not a subtype of type 'String'
Below is the code I used (pasted only notification part here). No issue in flutter doctor also.

```
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';

class _Home extends State<HomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
     static FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
     FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = new FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    firebaseCloudMessaging_Listeners();

  }
void firebaseCloudMessaging_Listeners() {
    var android = new AndroidInitializationSettings('mipmap/ic_launcher',);
    var ios = new IOSInitializationSettings();
    var platform = new InitializationSettings(android, ios);

    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(platform,onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification);

    if (Platform.isIOS) iOS_Permission();
    _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token){
      //FCM=token;
    }).catchError((onError){
      print("blb07 "+onError.toString());
    });

    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print('blb07 on message $message');
        handleNotification(message['data']['message']);
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print('blb07 on resume $message');
        handleNotification(message['data']['message']);
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print('blb07 on launch $message');
        handleNotification(message['data']['message']);
      },
    );
  }

  void iOS_Permission() {
    _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
        IosNotificationSettings(sound: true, badge: true, alert: true)
    );
    _firebaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered
        .listen((IosNotificationSettings settings)
    {
      print("Settings registered: $settings");
    });
  }
  Future onSelectNotification(String payload) async {
    await Navigator.push(
      context,
      new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new DisplayNotifications()),
    );
  }

  void handleNotification(String message) async{
      var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = new AndroidNotificationDetails(
          'default1', 'Sureworks ', 'Sureworks app notifications',
          importance: Importance.Max, priority: Priority.High);
      var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = new IOSNotificationDetails();
      var platformChannelSpecifics = new NotificationDetails(
          androidPlatformChannelSpecifics, iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);
      print("blb07 start");
      try{
        await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(0, 'Sureworks', message, platformChannelSpecifics,payload: 'item')
            .then((onValue){
          print("blb07 finished");
        }).catchError((onError)=>print("blb07 "+onError));
        print("blb07 hello end line");
      }catch(e){
        print("blb07 error "+e.toString());
      }
  }
}
```

my pubspec.yaml dependencies

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  http: ^0.11.3+16
  shared_preferences: ^0.4.2
  firebase_messaging: ^4.0.0+1
  firebase_core: ^0.2.5
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.7.0
  paging: ^0.1.0
  flutter_local_notifications: ^0.6.1
```

What could be the problem? messages passing to the handleNotification funtion are string format only. No problem in Receiving notification data from server.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run `pod install` ?
If not its likely that there is something missing on the native side.

Simply open up a terminal and navigate to your flutter project root.
Then `cd` into the `iOS` folder and run `pod install`.

This should fix your error.

Comment: No didn't run that command. Now I did it in terminal in IOS folder. It gave an error 'pod' command not found. I'm using ubuntu OS.

Comment: Ah okey. It seem'd your developing for iOS. Then Pod is not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Migrated my Android to AndroidX. Now it's working fine. Spent more than 4 hours on it. 
Migrate to AndroidX and "Invalidate caches and restart" did the trick.